# Can I use condition in regular expression in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

still dealing with regular expressions.
I've got file that will contain a combination of lines. I need to pick up everything from A to the right. If character A is inside // - it's not counted. If A is the first character of the line - everything should be picked up. There would be three scenarios:

```
    my $str = 'some before/some.A;hi99/some after A text goes here'
    my $str1 = 'A some before/some.A;hi99/some after A text goes here'
    my $str2 = 'some before/some.A;hi99/some after
```

Otput should be:
 A text goes here 
 A some before/some.A;hi99/some after A text goes here 
 nothing 
I can match up A inside // but I don't know if it's possible to check other two conditions inside regex?

```
  $str =~ /([^\/]+.*[A]+.*[^\/]+)/g;
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing it without one super regex? I can't see the advantage.

Comment: alfa64 - I haven't yet. I can see how to check if A is the first element but no idea how to check if there is A somewhere after /..A../

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) to do an amusing transformation:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    my $odd = 0;
    my $pass = 0;

    my $line = join '/', grep {$pass || (($odd ^= 1) && s/.*?A/A/ && ++$pass)} split '/';

    print $line
        ? "(pass) - $line\n"
        : "(fail)\n";
}

__DATA__
some before/some.A;hi99/some after A text goes here
A some before/some.A;hi99/some after A text goes here
some before/some.A;hi99/some after
```

Outputs

```
(pass) - A text goes here
(pass) - A some before/some.A;hi99/some after A text goes here
(fail)
```